# Why does the default JS bind function works and why my polyfill for the bind returns undefined?

Tags: javascript, function, polyfills

I am trying to write the polyfill for the js bind function over a multiply function. The js bind function is giving the correct answer `8` but my polyfill is giving `undefined`. The main multiply function is returning all the params correctly though.

```
Function.prototype.myBind = function (...args) {
  let obj = this;
  let params = args.slice(1);

  return function (...param2) {
    obj.apply(args[0], [...params, ...param2]);
  };
};

let mul = (a, b) => {
  console.log(13, a, b, a * b);
  return a * b;
};

let mulFour = mul.bind(this, 4);
let myMulFour = mul.myBind(this, 4);

console.log(mulFour(2));
console.log(myMulFour(2));
```

Comment: You forgot to return the function call

Comment: Sorry, @CertainPerformance not clear, I did return the function here: 
`  return function (...param2) {
    obj.apply(args[0], [...params, ...param2]);
  }; `

Comment: Not the call of it. `obj.apply(args[0], [...params, ...param2]);`

Comment: Can you please clarify a bit more, @CertainPerformance. That would be a massive help.

Comment: Add the `return` keyword.

Comment: Thank you so much, @CertainPerformance works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

CertainPerformance was correct, needed to return the `obj.apply(args[0], [...params, ...param2]);` again.

The polyfill would go like this:

```
Function.prototype.myBind = function (...args) {
  let obj = this;
  let params = args.slice(1);

  return function (...param2) {
    return obj.apply(args[0], [...params, ...param2]);
  };
};
```